# Как в с# парсить куки созданные в javaScript?

Tags: c#, auth, qiwi

Собственно вопрос задан. Часто на сайтах некоторые куки задаются не через Response, динамически при отработке javaScript. Какие существуют пути для получения этих куки? Можно ли их получить не прикручивая к проекту браузер?

Видел библу Noesis.javaScipt. Но не совсем понимаю ее смысл. Может я что-то не понял, но как по мне она просто позволяет писать код в синтаксисе js. т.к. все функции вызываемые в js - нужно переопределять, как бы привязывать свои функции к именам функций в js.

ЗЫ Для правильных программистов, мне это нужно для авторизации на киви. Хочу парсить данные своего кошелька для онлайн оплаты. Открывать официальный онлайн магазин, проходить верификацию в киви для такого мелкого софтика - явно лишнее.

Comment: Вам нужно выпонять js, чтобы тот создавал вам куки. Здесь не в парсинге дело.

Comment: Ну я про либу в курсе. Не понимаю ее просто. Она требует для каждой функции в js коде выделять функцию в приложении. Каким образом мне тогда запускать какие-то функции криптографии. Если мне придется все функции js переносить в c#, то нафига вообще эта либа.  
Или есть способ попроще?